# What condition variables can do that unlock+yield cannot?

Tags: mutex, sleep, condition-variable

In POSIX, there's the requirement that when a `wait` is called on a condition variable and a mutex, the 2 operations - unlocking the mutex and blocking the thread, be atomically performed, in such way that any `broadcast`/`signal` should take effect as if they happened *after* blocking. I suppose there should be equivalent requirements on C11, C++ condition variables as well, and I won't go on to do a verbose enumeration.

However, in some system (such as many people's nostalgia WinXP), there wasn't a condition variable mechanism. Instead, they have to perform a `unlock`+`yield` to achieve similar (same?) effect. And this works, because even if the `broadcast`/`signal` occured in-between the `unlock` and `yield`, when the thread is re-scheduled, its observable behavior is the same as if the wake occured after the block. WinXP supported mutex, and it had an `SleepEx` function that can work like an `yield`.

So it begs the question: What condition variables can do, that `unlock`+`yield` cannot?

---

In response to the comment: I use WinXP as an example because it happens to be one that supported mutex but not condvar, and the fact that it's one generation's memory. Of course, we assume correctness and reasonable performance, and the question doesn't specifically ask Windows and it asks *any implementation in general*.

Comment: Most of these things are not about "observable effect" but about performance and correctness. Event objects in the old Windows produced a cornucopia of most evil bugs which gave Windows a reputation rather far removed from "well regarded". This, in turn, made Microsoft invest a lot of effort into improving synchapi.h and related APIs.

Comment: @oakad, observable effect, performance, and to some extent, correctness are the main concerns of my question. If Windows isn't a good example in your opinion, then any other implementation which you believe can make a point will do.

Comment: @oakad: That's a pretty distorted representation of reality. XP was well regarded by many, and to those whom it wasn't, the reason wasn't event objects. Events are pretty great and have been sorely missed in *nix systems. And don't forget IOCP which was an even better way to handle events that Linux had no better answer to until a handful of years ago (and even then Windows introduced I/O rings too).

Comment: @DannyNiu: btw your question is great. I've had a similar question for a long time too - I've yet to come across any problem where I've felt condition variables are the best solution. Don't let *nix lovers distract you. Although, if you don't get a good answer here CS.SE might make sense to ask on.

Comment: @user541686 I hope you're aware of the fact that futexes were implemented in Linux around 2003. Event objects can be trivially implemented in terms of futexes, yet all those people "sorely missing" events on Linux somehow neglected to implement any. :-)

Comment: @oakad: I'm indeed well aware. If you think futexes are the right solution to every synchronization problem, I have... news for you. P.S. They didn't neglect to *implement* them, eventfds have been implemented in Linux since 2007 or so. They're simply neglected, is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CVs can do timed wait, while you cannot control when you wake up from an yield.

CVs in the POSIX standard can wait until an absolute point in time passes. The reason it's not relative is that

1. if you want to wait for an absolute time
2. you have to do the math backwards to calculate a relative time, and
3. if the thread is preempted between the calculation and the CV wait,
4. the actual wake up could be delayed.